# Is there a way to hook java methods?

Tags: java, hook, interceptor

I'm looking for a way to hook Java methods.
I read about `MethodInterceptor` but I got messed up trying to use it and I don't know if that's what I'm looking for. I want to intercept functions from the `java.lang.System` for example and not from the loaded jar.

Basically I need some simple hooking just like the win32api style (redirecting the call to my code and then jumping back to the original function).

Is that possible?

Comment: Why? What is your *real* problem?

Comment: I need to hook several methods and check their arguments before I'm executing them

Comment: Why? Did you consider using AOP?

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0):

I think AOP might be an answer to your question.

Take a look at [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). You might want to use an "around advice" to check parameters of specific methods before executing them.

As in:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

    @Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
    public Object doParamChecking(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeType someArg, ...) throws Throwable {
        if (checkParamOK(someArg, ...)) {
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
        return SomethingOtherwise();
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a way to hook a method in a win32 style where i'm redirecting the call to my code and then returning to the original code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `AoP`. Using AoP, it is possible to do operations before, after and around a method invocation. You can check the [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) for Aspect Oriented Programming.

[This](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html) aspectj doc provides a glimpse into AspectJ programming.